# JPList filter search in database

Tags: javascript, laravel, jplist

The page opens very late because the jplist pagination I am using now loads all the data. How can I get other pages to load only when clicked but include filtering?

eg: when the page is first loaded it will load only the data on the first page but when filtered it will also filter the data on the other page.

```
  <div 
                    class="jplist-group"
                    data-control-type="checkbox-group-filter"
                           data-control-action="filter"
                           data-control-name="server">
                <ul class="widget-list cz-filter-list list-unstyled pt-1" style="max-height: 12rem;" data-simplebar data-simplebar-auto-hide="false">
                
                  <li class="cz-filter-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">  
                     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input id="TR" data-path=".TR" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                      <label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="TR">TR</label>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                   <li class="cz-filter-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">  
                     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input id="EU" data-path=".EU" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                      <label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="EU">EU</label>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                      <li class="cz-filter-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">  
                     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input id="NA" data-path=".NA" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                      <label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="NA">NA</label>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                      <li class="cz-filter-item d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">  
                     <div class="custom-control custom-checkbox">
                      <input id="AP" data-path=".AP" type="checkbox" class="custom-control-input">
                      <label class="custom-control-label cz-filter-item-text" for="AP">AP</label>
                    </div>
                  </li>
                   
                    
                 
                 </ul>
                 </div>
```

Jplist pagination:

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12" align="right">
            <div class="jplist-panel box panel-top">                        
                        
                
                    <div 
                       class="jplist-pagination" 
                       data-control-type="pagination" 
                       data-control-name="paging" 
                       data-control-action="paging"
                       data-items-per-page="{{ 21 }}">
                    </div>          
                    
                </div>
              
            </div>
        </div>
```

Controller php:

```
$itemData['item'] = Items::with('ratings')->select('items.item_id','items.item_liked','items.item_slug', 'items.item_category', 'items.item_category_type',')->leftjoin('users', 'users.id', '=', 'items.user_id')->where('items.item_status','=',1)->where('items.drop_status','=','no')->where('items.item_category_parent','=',$category_id)->orderBy('items.created_last', 'desc')->get();
```